# Is AXA insurance acceptable for long stay French Carte de Sejour?

Tags: france, health-insurance

I am renewing my French carte de sejour and want to change insurance to AXA.  Does anyone know if AXA Schengen Ins is acceptable?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt it is fit for long term residency (you mention Carte de Séjour) as the [FAQ](https://www.axa-schengen.com/en/FAQ) says :

> Q: I am living in a European country, can I buy?
>
> A: Yes, you can. You
> will be covered outside of your country of residence.